# Eat your beans - how many make five meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

There was a Facebook friend commented like this on my meme-post:

> Just eat your beans - by the way how many make five?

I did a quick-research and came up with [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/wordhistories.net/2018/09/17/beans-make-five/amp/). Still don't get it. What does it mean? He's from UK by the way.

Oh, although, probably it won't be necessary, the meme I had posted was:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UK, if you say that someone knows 'how many beans make five', you are saying that the person is sensible and intelligent.

[How many beans make five (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/know_how_many_beans_make_five)